# Continuity of $v: \mathcal{B} (M;N) \times M \rightarrow N$, $v(f,x) = f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d_M)$, $(N,d_N)$ be metric spaces and  $v:  \mathcal{B} (M;N) \times M \rightarrow N$,  $v(f,x) = f(x)$.

Then $v$ is continuous at $(f_0,x_0)\in \mathcal{B}(M;N) \times M$ $\iff$ $f_0 : M \rightarrow N$ is continuous at $x_0 \in M$

$\mathcal{B}(M;N)$ is equipped with the metric  $d(f,g) =\underset{x \in M}{\sup}\{d_ N (f(x),g(x))\} $ and 
$\mathcal{B}(M;N) \times M$ is equipped with
$\rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0)) = \max\{d(f,f_0), d_M(x,x_0)\}$

**My attempt**

$\Leftarrow )$

Suppose that  $f_0$ is continuous at $x_0$. Then 
given $\varepsilon>0$  there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that:
$$d_M(x,x_0) < \delta_1 \Rightarrow d_ N (f_0(x), f_0(x_0)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$
Take $0<\delta < \min \{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \delta_1 \}$.

If $\rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0)) < \delta$ then $d(f,f_0)< \delta $ and $d_M(x,x_0) < \delta$.

Thus, if $\rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0)) < \delta $, we have:

$$ d_N(v(f,x),v(f_0,x_0)) =  d_ N (f(x),f_0(x_0))  \leq   d_ N (f(x),f_0(x)) +   d_ N (f_0(x), f_0(x_0)) $$
$$\leq d(f,f_0) +  d_N(f_0(x), f_0(x_0)) < \delta + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}  < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}  + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} 
 = \varepsilon $$
Then $v$ is continuous at $(f_0,x_0)$.

I'm having trouble with the second implication.

$\Rightarrow )$

Suppose that $v$ is continuous at  $(f_0,x_0)$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$  there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that:
$$  \rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0))  < \delta_1 \Rightarrow d_N(v(f,x),v(f_0,x_0)) =  d_ N (f(x),f_0(x_0)) < 
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

Take $0<\delta < \min \{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \delta_1 \}$.

**If** $  \rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0))  < \delta$, we have:
$$d_ N (f_0(x),f_0(x_0)) \leq   d_ N (f_0(x),f(x))  + d_ N (f(x),f_0(x_0))$$
$$\leq  d(f,f_0) + d_ N (f(x),f_0(x_0)) \leq  \rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0)) +  d_ N (f(x),f_0(x_0)) < \varepsilon$$

I don't think this proves that $f_0$ is continuous at $x_0$.

We should have something like $d_M(x,x_0) < \delta \Rightarrow d_N(f_0(x),f(x_0)) < \varepsilon$.

How can I finish this argument?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{B}(M;N)$?

Comment: Yes, @Yeldarbskich, but $d_M(x,x_0) < \delta$ does not imply $\rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0))  < \delta$.

Comment: $ \mathcal{B} (M;N)$ is the set of all bounded functions from $M$ into $N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working past the flubb in my comment, you should be more particular when finishing the argument. Begin as you have by supposing that $v$ is continuous at $(f_0,x_0)$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there is a $\delta >0$ such that $d_N(f(x),f_0(x_0))<\epsilon$ whenever $\rho((f,x),(f_0,x_0)) < \delta$. You need to consider which elements in the ball $B_{\delta}((f_0,x_0))$ will give you what you want. In particular take $f=f_0$, then $(f_0,x) \in B_{\delta}((f_0,x_0))$ if $d_M(x,x_0)<\delta$.